# Graphing equations using HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas

Needed help with graphing of equations on the HTML5 canvas. I am looking at developing something like this:

http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/linear_equation/systems-of-equation/interactive-system-of-linear-equations.php

Since this is also going to be accessed on a mobile - need to have touch to drag the anchor points

The process would be:
Having the equation graphed on the canvas
There may be inputs - which if the user changed - it would reflect on the graph
Getting the dragging feature for the desktop browsers
Getting the dragging on the mobile device

I was looking at using the Kineticjs - wanted to know if the above could be achieved using Kineticjs. Else, any other library and any help/tips on how to go about this would be appreciated

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you was aware of the sencha charts. If u do it as open source then u can get sencha charts for free. check dis link.[sencha charts gpl](http://www.sencha.com/products/charts/download/sencha-touch-charts-1.0/249)

and check their website. U will get some idea.

Comment: Thanks, but can I graph any sort of equation on SenchaTouch?

Comment: Am not workin in it, so i dont know well about it. May be there are some ways to include your logics and equations in it.